# How can I remove the white space between images?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, margin

I'm developing my first Android application, and I would like to build a main meno with two consecutive images an then a TabWidget with some tabs. I'm using Android 2.3.

I don't know why but, between the imges, it appears some white space that looks so ugly...I'm triyng all the time modifying paddin and margin but no works... Anyone knows what happens?

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <!--  android:background="#000000" -->


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/TwiceBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/twice_bar"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Banner_publicidad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/banner_publicidad"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

     </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried adding android:adjustViewBounds="true" to your ImageViews?

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a tweak, `fitStart` will only move the image to the top/left of the image view, it wont fill the space.

`cropCenter` allow the image to fill the space by how you ask it, So if the image view is wider than the image, meaning that it need to crop the bottom and top to fill the space, it will do so.

Generally the `Center` scaleTypes are the best to use to fill the space.

```
<LinearLayout
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <ImageView android:id="@+id/TwiceBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/twice_bar"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Banner_publicidad"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/banner_publicidad"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

 <TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```